# Не запускается стандартный helloworld в эмуляторе

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.

Создал проект в Андроид студии. Ничего там не изменил. Запускаю проект, запускается эмулятор (очень долго, более 3 минут). Эмулятор запустился. И в logcat вылетает это:

```
    06-10 12:14:05.461    1250-1250/com.hangover.a1basicviews.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a9bba8)
06-10 12:14:05.491    1250-1250/com.hangover.a1basicviews.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hangover.a1basicviews.app, PID: 1250
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hangover.a1basicviews.app/com.hangover.a1basicviews.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
            at com.hangover.a1basicviews.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Где-то читал, что это из-за того, что долго запускается и можно изменить допустимое время, но не понятно где. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам же пишет

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

и решение: [ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom)

Comment: Не совсем понял. Я еще новичок. Объясните, что это, и что нужно сделать?

Comment: Ребят, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам написал пользователь с логином *KoVadim*, что проблема связана с:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Это значит, что у вас конфликт с темой, которую вы выбрали для приложения. Вы можете поменять тему в разделе ***Design***, когда откроете ***xml*** файл с вашей основной активити, скорее всего это ***MainActivity***. Так же можете подшаманить в ***AndroidManifest.xml***

В разделе ***application*** найдете такие строки:

```
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Параметр строчки с темой (***android:theme***) измените на нужный. От вас, как я понял среда требует ***Theme.AppCompat***. То бишь вам нужно заменить ее на такую:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat".
```

Должно работать ;)